# Reset and stop a preloader-GIF after first loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif, preloader

Currently building a site that displays a "fake" preloader when entering the side - in this case an animated logo, GIF ~3.5sec long, that is shown for exactly one loop before fading out.

The preloader itself is working flawlessly, problems only arise when the page is reloaded: the GIF starts at a random position, leading me to the assumption that the GIF is being replayed in the background. 
This would normally not be an issue, since preloader-gifs are meant to keep looping, but in this case a logo builds itself up, and start- and end-frame a completly different and no good for looping.

How can I fix this?

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PreLoader/preloader.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="PreLoader/preloader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="preloader">
            <span class="preloader-gif"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
.preloader{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #7BAABE;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.preloader .preloader-gif{
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -500px ;
    background-image: url("preloader.gif");  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // preloader
  $(window).load(function(){
    $(".preloader").delay(3500).fadeOut(500).stopp();

  })

})
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I know it was a long time ago but here is a simple solution for it with
solution for using background image - can be used for img also with tiny changes:

```
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <script>
        const loaderMaker = () => {
        const preFix = window.origin;
        const loaderGifUrl = 
        `url('${preFix}/ImagePath.gif?a=${Math.random()}')`;
        //console.log(loaderGifUrl); (to check the given url is right);
        document.querySelector('.loader').style.background = `${loaderGifUrl} no-repeat 
    50% 50%`;
        };
        loaderMaker();
    </script>
```